# Four unrelated rebuses

Tags: rebus

I've made rebuses #1-4 below, presumably from easiest to hardest. What phrase is each trying to say? First to solve all four gets the check mark!

**#1**

[image: Heart]

**#2**
[image: Letters]

**#3**
[image: Duff]

**#4**
[image: Sofa]

*Note: the phrases are unrelated.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 is

> LOVE AT FIRST SIGHT

2 is

> MIXED FEELINGS

3 is

> FALL ON DEAF EARS

4 is

> NOT SO FAST (Not Sofa St.)

Comment: Check mark as promised, but majority credit to other respondents and especially @Avi.

Comment: Wow, I even considered and discounted that one :) Good find!

Comment: Yeah haha gotta give Avi most of the credit for this one

Comment: I had "unusually fine legs" for 2, but I guess yours works too ;-)

Comment: @Bass "fine legs all over the place" he said at the club

Comment: Can you please explain #4? I don't get it :((

Comment: @mimic No problem, added an explanation for 4

Comment: @anodyne hmm where can I see it? I understand NOT SOFA but ST=?

Comment: @mimic ah, "st." is the abbreviation for "street" (hence the road and the period)

Comment: @anodyne ah, okay. I didn't see it meant "street". Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

1 is obviously

> **LOVE AT FIRST SIGHT**

2 is (thanks @Rand al'Thor)

> **MIXED FEELINGS**

3 is to

> **FALL ON DEAF EARS**

4 I'm unsure, but the rest I'm confident of.

Comment: 4 could be something to do with "seat belt", considering a beltway/highway as a "belt"

Comment: Oh so *that's* what those things are in #1! I couldn't make them out.

Comment: You're a shoo-in for the check mark, just one more to go! (I really should've posted these separately - assigning the check is hard when multiple people help. I'll post one at a time next time.)

Comment: Whoever gets #4 deserves the checkmark because it's miles tougher than all the others :P I admit defeat

Answer (score 7):

Solution to #2 is

> MIXED FEELINGS.

Solution to #1 might be

> THIRD WHEEL, although I'm not convinced.

Comment: Appreciate it but won't comment until all four are proposed :)

Answer (score 5):

1.

> **cross my heart** *(crosshair over a heart)*

2.

> **mixed feelings** *(word "feelings" mixed up)*

3.

> **Afraid of falls** *(afraid-Duff under pictures of Fall)*

4.

> **unsituated** *(un-seat-way-dot)*

Comment: Whoa, interesting tries. Fantastic creativity. Only #2 is my intended answer though.

Answer (score 3):

My guess for #4

> *NOT SO FAR OUT* (NOT+SOFA+ROUT(E), dot acts like a comma, meaning "remove last letter of the word").

Comment: So close! It's not rot13(ebhgr) and the dot means something else